# How to prevent Host 'focusin' and 'focusout' ? [StencilJS]

Tags: jsx, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm creating a custom`select` form control and when it has a state `disabled` I need to skip `focusin` and `focusout` events.

This code without disabled validation doesn't work, the `focusin` is still emited.

```js
@Element() private element: HTMLElement;

public componentWillLoad() {
  this.element.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

Comment: `this.element` will not be defined until after the component loaded. Does it work in `componentDidLoad()`?

Comment: Afaik the element reference should already exist in `componentWillLoad` as well. Where in the DOM does the element live that causes the event?

Comment: (see https://webcomponents.dev/edit/8VsXghnUPUvjwvu0vL11?pm=1, the element is already defined in `componentWillLoad`)